# What is the difference between text and variable with this text in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

nginx:1.21.5 docker container.

there is two similar (as I think) configs:

```
server {
...
set $target_token "http://token-container:80";
  location /token/ {
    proxy_pass $target_token/;
    expires -1;
    proxy_read_timeout 60;
    proxy_set_header Host               $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    }
}
```

and

```
server {
...
  location /token/ {
    proxy_pass http://token-container:80/;
    expires -1;
    proxy_read_timeout 60;
    proxy_set_header Host               $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    }
}
```

First one has problems with cashing. (loaded page is blank. js didnt loaded)

Please look at the picture: (all items sizes are the same)

[image]

And the same page with the second config:

[image]

Why the usage of the variable spoil the page caching behavior?

Comment: Looks like the Caching is not involved here. At least in proper manner. There is the  same issue with the 200 response. If I have any variable inside the `proxy_pass` in the `location` block, the server return the first document instead of the all others.

Answer (score 0):

Variable in the proxy_pass force you to handle URI too, otherwise it will be dropped. Something like this `proxy_pass $upstream/api/$1$is_args$args;`

I got it from: [External resource: dev.to. Author: Daniel Albuschat](https://dev.to/danielkun/nginx-everything-about-proxypass-2ona)